# Use CTE To Create Subset of Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I'm wanting to create a subset of data for testing purposes, where I start with a Users table, select X of type a, Y of type b, Z of type c (and so on), and create a new table containing those users. I then need to to create all related tables (with the necessary records), and then all related tables to those...

I'm fairly certain the best way to do this is a recursive common table expression, however I don't have much experience with those and was hoping someone could help me out. So far I have the below, but have noticed two things:

1. Level 2 seems to contain everything that was in level 1, in addition to the new records I'd expect
2. This doesn't actually create/insert the records yet (I still need help with that)

   ```
   WITH cte AS
   (
       SELECT DISTINCT fk.object_id, fk.schema_id, fk.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id, t.schema_id AS referenced_schema_id, fk.referenced_object_id, ic.column_id AS referenced_column_id, 1 AS Level
       FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
           INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.object_id
           INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fc ON fk.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
           INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON fk.referenced_object_id = i.object_id AND i.is_primary_key = 1
           INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
       WHERE fk.type = 'F' 
           AND fk.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users', N'U')

       UNION ALL

       SELECT fk.object_id, fk.schema_id, fk.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id, t.schema_id, fk.referenced_object_id, ic.column_id AS referenced_column_id, cte.Level + 1
       FROM sys.foreign_keys fk     
           INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.object_id
           INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fc ON fk.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
           INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON fk.referenced_object_id = i.object_id AND i.is_primary_key = 1
           INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
           INNER JOIN cte ON fk.referenced_object_id = cte.parent_object_id
       WHERE fk.type = 'F' 
           AND fk.parent_object_id <> cte.referenced_object_id
   ),
   cteHierarchy AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT
           OBJECT_NAME(cte.object_id) AS ReferringKey,
           SCHEMA_NAME(cte.schema_id) AS ReferringSchema,
           OBJECT_NAME(cte.parent_object_id) as ReferringTable,
           COL_NAME(cte.parent_object_id,cte.parent_column_id) ReferringColumn,
           SCHEMA_NAME(cte.referenced_schema_id) AS ReferencedSchema,
           OBJECT_NAME(cte.referenced_object_id) as ReferencedTable,
           COL_NAME(cte.referenced_object_id,cte.referenced_column_id) ReferencedColumn,
           Level
       FROM cte
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM cteHierarchy
   ORDER BY Level, ReferencedSchema, ReferencedTable, ReferringTable;
   ```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Please share some sample data and your desired results. It will go a long way to helping us understand what you are after instead of having to reverse engineer your non-working SQL to derive your intentions.

Comment: While `fk.parent_object_id <> cte.referenced_object_id` in the recursive term isn't a problem, it does seem a little odd. This is essentially saying "Don't bring records through where the grandparent is the same as the child". Do you have cycling issues in this data that this is necessary?

Comment: @JNevill The users table has a self join, and I'd read that absent the line you quoted I'd experience infinite recursion. My understanding is that it's saying "don't bring records through where the *parent* is the same as the child".

Comment: I think the join back on your cte is on the wrong field.

Comment: The way your cte is written the "Child" here is the CTE record in your Recursive Term (the second SELECT): `INNER JOIN cte ON fk.referenced_object_id = cte.parent_object_id`. "Go get the parent record (fk) for this child (cte)" is what that says; you are climbing up a tree, not down. So the WHERE predicate `AND fk.parent_object_id <> cte.referenced_object_id` essentially says "For this child (cte.referenced_object_id) insure it isn't the same as the grandparent `fk.parent_object_id`. I think you may need to rethink how you are joining here if that logic doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: @jnevill Thank you, spot on about the join. Changed it to `fk.referenced_object_id <> cte.referenced_object_id` and it's now behaving as expected.

Comment: That makes more sense "Don't grab the parent, if the parent is the same as the child". I'm glad that did the trick!